# MongoDB + Ruby: updating records in an iteration

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Using MongoDB and the Ruby driver, I'm trying to calculate the rankings for players in my app, so I'm sorting by (in this case) pushups, and then adding a rank field and value per object.

```
pushups = coll.find.sort(["pushups", -1] )
pushups.each_with_index do |r, idx| 
    r[:pushups_rank] = idx + 1
    coll.update( {:id => r }, r, :upsert => true)
    coll.save(r)
end
```

This approach does work, but is this the best way to iterate over objects and update each one? Is there a better way to calculate a player's rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to do the entire update on the server by executing a javascript function:

```
update_rank = "function(){
 var rank=0;
 db.players.find().sort({pushups:-1}).forEach(function(p){
   rank +=1;
   p.rank = rank;
   db.players.save(p);
 });
}"
cn.eval( update_rank )
```

(Code assumes you have a "players" collection in mongo, and a ruby variable `cn` that holds a conection to your database)

Comment: I think it's the right approach as well. Note that using an update with $set rather than a save might be more efficient: db.players.update({_id: p._id}, {$set: {rank: rank}})  or something

Comment: Also note that eval locks the entire database. This won't scale, either with a lot of concurrent request and/or as players grows. FWIW, I was doing ranking in MongoDB also, and I switched that specific logic to a Redis sorted set. I blogged about my positive experience: http://openmymind.net/2011/5/8/Practical-NoSQL-Solving-a-Real-Problem-w-Mongo-Red/

Comment: Oh, I definitely came across your post in my research, @KarlSeguin. Great stuff there!